# sort and partition using random fields not just the first k fields

Tags: sorting, hadoop, partitioning

I'm using hadoop `streaming` to do some job, and I encounter a problem, here it is.

The input file to `mapper` has, say 3 fields, in each line. I know that `mapper`'s output will be sorted and partitioned before feeding the data to `reducer`, and my problem is

1.Can I sort/partition those data using the **3rd** field? 
2.Can I sort the data using the whole line?

PS:

AFAIK, the sort-key or partition-key should be the first k fields of each line, right? If so, does it mean I should move those fields into the front of line in `mapper`?

Answer (score 0):

Mapper's output are sorted only on the basis of the key.

So, say you have input record as : **field1**, **field2** ,**field3**

1) if you do not want to the first field to be your key and can manage if your *3rd* field is key then you do not need to do anything else, so you can do something like follows:

```
output.collect(new Text(field3), new Text(field1 + ","+field2)); //Old API
context.write(new Text(field3), new Text(field1 + ","+field2)); //New API
```

2) Similarly you can have everything as your key and null as value, this would result in getting sorted as per whole line, something like follows can be done:

```
output.collect(new Text(field1 + ","+field2 + "," + field3), null); // Old API
context.write(new Text(field1 + ","+field2 + "," + field3), null); // New API
```

No, it doesn't matter at all in which sequence the fields are in the input file as far as the sorting is concerned, it is only depended on what are you emitting from the mapper as mapper output.

But if you need to have **field1** as your key in mapper output but want to do a secondary sort on **field3**, then read : [How to do a secondary sort on values ?](http://bigdataspeak.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-how-to-do-a-secondary-sort-on-values/)

Comment: ya I get it, but you should rather say that you are NOT using java, as even using custom jar's you can do hadoop streaming.

Comment: and my point 1 and 2 should be valid in any case! aren't you emitting any output from your mapper code? or you have absolute no control over your mapper code ?

Comment: Well, I already know how to do it in streaming now, thanks man.

Comment: Oh that's great, kindly submit the solution here too as another answer :)